# Duda con inner join

Tags: sql, join

Tengo una base de datos con dos tablas. Una es la tabla de `coche` y otra de `ruta`:

Tabla `coche`:

```
pk_coche    modelo      
-------------------
1           Modelo 1
2           Modelo 2 
3           Modelo 3
```

Tabla `ruta`:

```
pk_ruta     fk_coche    kms_inicio     kms_final
-------------------------------------------------
1           1              200.000        210.000
2           3              300            0
```

La columna de `kms_inicio` se refiera a los kilómetros con los que un coche inicia la ruta por ejemplo con `200.000 kms`. Mientras la columna de `kms_final`esté en `0`, significa que ese coche está en ruta.

Bien, mi problema viene al crear una sentencia sql para que me devuelva los coches que no están en ruta, para que no haya dos coches en una misma ruta. Como veis el coche `Modelo 2`, no está en ruta asi que con mi sentencia si me aparece, el problema es que `Modelo 1` me debería de aparecer ya que ese coche ha terminado su ruta. Pero con mi sentencia solo me aparece `Modelo 2`, que no ha iniciado ninguna ruta. Mi sentencia es la siguiente:

```
SELECT pk_coche, modelo FROM coche v 
left JOIN ruta r ON v.pk_coche=r.fk_coche 
WHERE r.pk_ruta IS NULL
```

Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Con un `inner join` de coches a ruta y con la clausula where que has aplicado, solo debería mostrarte los coches que están en ruta, prueba a hacer un `left outer join` para que te muestre todos los registros de coche, independientemente de que tengan ruta asignada o no.

Comment: @rencinas en principio con la clausula where que he aplicado no me aparecen coches, pero me debería aparecer uno que no esté en ruta

Comment: pero igualmente le estás diciendo que el campo `kms_inicio` sea 0 por tanto con esa clausula no debería aparecer ningún coche en ruta, o puede darse el caso de coches en ruta com `kms_inicio = 0`?

Comment: Perdón, no me he explicado bien. `kms_inicio` lo que significa son los kilometros con los que el coche inicia esa ruta, por ejemplo con 200.000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xerox,  **en vez de `= null` debes usar `IS NULL`...** de lo contrario no va a funcionar.

En la prueba que he hecho, hay tres coches, aquel cuyo `pk_coche` es igual a `2` no está en ruta, mientras que los coches `1` y `3` están en ruta.

Si tú quieres mostrar los coches que no están en ruta, si los datos están bien insertados, bastaría con esto:

```
/*Coches no en ruta*/
SELECT * FROM coche c 
LEFT JOIN ruta r ON c.pk_coche=r.fk_coche 
WHERE r.pk_ruta IS NULL;
```

El resultado sería:

```
pk_coche    modelo      pk_ruta     fk_coche    kms_inicio       kms_final
2           Modelo 2    NULL        NULL        NULL             NULL
```

Y para mostrar los coches que están en ruta:

```
/*Coches en ruta*/
SELECT * FROM coche c 
LEFT JOIN ruta r ON c.pk_coche=r.fk_coche 
WHERE r.pk_ruta IS NOT NULL;
```

El resultado sería:

```
pk_coche    modelo      pk_ruta     fk_coche    kms_inicio     kms_final
1           Modelo 1    1           1           100            200
3           Modelo 3    2           3           300            800
```

---

Puedes ver el demo completo aquí:  <kbd>**[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/JBGDV10167)**</kbd>

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76157/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-duda-con-inner-join).

Answer (score 0):

Para que te devuelvan los coches que no están en ruta, tiene que haber registros en la tabla *ruta* con kms_inicio a 0 o a *null*.

Compruebalo.

Si no, deberias cambiar el sentido de la Query, de INNER JOIN, a LEFT JOIN. El LEFT JOIN te sacaria los coches aunque no estén en la tabla *ruta*.

Comment: Claro, esa es mi duda, la cuestión es que no hay ninguna ruta con kms_inicio a 0 o a null porque se supone que todavía no ha hecho ruta

Comment: Entonces cambia a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Lo he intentado con el LEFT JOIN pero sigue sin aparecer ninguno

Comment: Mira, aquí está la prueba: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cb17ef/2/0

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido bien, quieres los coches que NO estén en ruta. Es decir, que no estén en la tabla rutas.

```
select coche.pk_coche, ruta.fk_coche
from coche 
left join ruta on coche.pk_coche = ruta.fk_coche
where ruta.fk_coche is null
```

este link te será de gran ayuda
https://donnierock.com/2014/03/04/diferencia-entre-inner-join-left-join-y-right-join-sql/

edit: Como dice el compañero, hay que poner IS NULL.

edit: Después de las aclaraciones:

```
/*Coches no en ruta*/
SELECT * FROM coche c 
LEFT JOIN ruta r ON c.pk_coche=r.fk_coche 
WHERE r.kms_final = 0 or  r.pk_ruta IS NULL;
```

Comment: Lo he intentado de la forma que tu me has dicho, ya que es más lógica que la mía pero sigue sin aparecer ningun coche

Comment: Mira, aquí está la prueba: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cb17ef/2/0

Comment: Como dice el compañero, hay que poner IS NULL, ya he editado

Comment: Estoy comprobando un error que encontré, esa función va de maravilla pero el problema está en que si el coche `Modelo 3` acaba la ruta con 800 kms, luego cuando ejecutas el código para ver cuáles no están en ruta pues sigue apareciendo solamente el `Modelo 2`, ya que es el único que no ha hecho ninguna ruta. Para entender mejor, con esa función solo me salen los coches que no han hecho ninguna ruta

Comment: En ese caso:
    /*Coches no en ruta*/
    SELECT * FROM coche c 
    LEFT JOIN ruta r ON c.pk_coche=r.fk_coche 
    WHERE r.kms_final = 0 or  r.pk_ruta IS NULL;

Así tenemos los que nunca han hecho una ruta y los que la han hecho, pero su kms_final es 0.